# shell script falls

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write my own script for comfortable tar-usage (and also become more experienced in shell) and my script falls:

```
cmd=$1
tarname=$2
files=${*:3}

echo_green(){
   echo -e "\033[1;32m$@\033[0m"
}
echo_blue(){
   echo -e "\033[1;34m$@\033[0m"
}
create(){
   echo_blue 'create'
   case $tarname in
      *.tar) tar -cvf $tarname $files; echo_green $tarname created;;
      *.tar.gz) tar -cvzf $tarname $files; echo $tarname created;;
      *.tar.bz2) tar -cvjf $tarname $files; echo_green $tarname created;;
   esac
}
show(){
   _cmd='tar -tv'
   case $tarname in
      *.tar) _cmd+='f' ;;
      *.tar.gz) _cmd+='zf' ;;
      *.tar.bz2) _cmd+='jf' ;;
   esac
   _cmd_all=$_cmd" $tarname | awk '{print \$6}' | cut -d'/' -f 1"
   echo $_cmd_all
   content="$($_cmd_all)"
   exit
   IFS='
'
   _cmd_folder=$_cmd" $tarname | head -1 | awk '{print \$6}' | cut -d'/' -f 1"
   echo $_cmd_folder
   folder="$($_cmd_folder)"
   all_in_one=1
   for l in $content; do 
      if [ ! $l = $folder ]; then
         all_in_one=0;
         break;
      fi
   done
   echo $all_in_one
}
case $cmd in
   "create") create;;
   "show") show;;
esac
```

error:

```
$ bash bash_lesson.sh show 4.tar 
tar -tvf 4.tar | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d'/' -f 1
tar: You may not specify more than one `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label' option
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

but if I just run problematic string in console, everything is ok:

```
$ tar -tvf 4.tar | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d'/' -f 1
test_dir
bash_lesson
```

Comment: Tarballs should *never* be created from a list of files.  Put the files in a directory and create a tarball of the directory.

Comment: Try: `content="$(eval $_cmd_all)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the string.  As it is, in the line 
`content="$($_cmd_all)"`, the shell is calling tar with the
arguments:  `-tvf 4.tar | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d'/' -f 1`
That is, it is passing `|` as an argument rather than evaluating it as 
a pipe.  `tar` sees two `-f` options and fails.  Just change the script to:

```
content="$(eval $_cmd_all)"
```

Comment: thanks:) also, I know about parent directory and I would consider it

Comment: hmm, I am stuck. I want to if user cast `my_script pack name.tar file1 file2` - create main folder in archive in pack files to it - how to do that?

Comment: `mkdir tmpdir; ln $files tmpdir; tar czf $tarname tmpdir; rm -rf tmpdir`

Comment: but what if current folder already contains tmpdir? of course I could start guessing for appropriate name, but it would be perfect if it would be possible to strongly specify this name - it should be equivalent to archive's name

Comment: Either have the user provide a name for the directory, or base it on $tarname, or simply abort if the user specifies more than one filename.